# Kind of "chroma key" using a key frame

Tags: chromakey, kdenlive

I am a professor at the university. I have been recording my lectures and using Kdenlive for editing. See [this example of my videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMG2ETzS-iy80kspoqaE2bgLWvZFf9i3u).

I am starting a new course, and this time I will have more time to do the editing. I would like to be able to, at a certain time, substitute my background (the wall and the white board) by some image (a slide with mathematical content made with [beamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX))).

Is it possible with Kdenlive?

It would be nice if, for example, I could use a keyframe where I do not appear as a map on what to erase. Of course, I would have to shave off the writing on the board. I thought of, for example, computing the difference and changing the color balance to make myself white and the background black, so I could use the result as some sort of mask.

I am new with Kdenlive and video editing in general. Is this a good approach? How exactly can I do it in Kdenlive?